# Error with R.id.display

Tags: android

In this line of code:

```
disp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
```

I get the error "display cannot be resolved or is not a field". Eclipse suggests the following:

- Create field 'display' in type 'id'
- Create constant 'display' in type 'id'
- Change to 'action settings'
- Change to 'hybrid'
- Change to 'none'
- Change to 'normal'
- Change to 'satellite'
- Change to 'terrain'

Comment: post your layout xml and check if you have imported `android.R;` if so remove that statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADD in the text view in your XML file

```
android:id="@+id/display"
```

You are good to go

Answer (score 2):

You might have defined id of your `TextView` in your layout wrongly. Check in your layout you should have defined `id` of `TextView` as `android:id="@+id/display`.

Answer (score 1):

`R` is a generated class from your resources. None of the suggested fixes would fix the underlying issue in your resource file.

The content view layout XML of your activity should have a `TextView` with `android:id="@+id/display"`.

Comment: @blackbelt That's one possibility but then there would likely be a a lot of other errors around `R` as well.

Comment: I agree, mine was only a suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you or your IDE automatically included the wrong R class. If you find an import like

```
import android.R;
```

remove this line and use the auto-generated R class from your project instead.